# Configure maven dependency resolution with in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2e, m2e-wtp

I use maven-2 in external mode in eclipse 4 (juno) with m2e and m2e-wtp plugin. In all our projects we usually define all the libraries (to the version) with in the pom. So we use non-transitive dependency resolution for our build. But when I import our projects from git to eclipse, the MavenDependency that gets resolved uses transitive dependency resolution. This is resulting in some issues, like i get some libraries copied to my classpath which I did not intend for. Is there a way to configure the nature of dependency resolution in eclipse so that it uses non-transitive dependency resolution.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not using transitive dependency resolution? You are getting against the idea of Maven, cause it's one of its basic ideas to handle transitive dependencies. If you like to that way you need to exclude all transitive dependencies of your dependencies this will result in a large number of exclusions.

Comment: So there is no way of instructing eclipse (m2e/m2e_wtp)to use non-transitive dependency resolution while assembling the 'Maven Dependencies'? I believe there should be some way, other than manually adding exclusions.